# 20 Amp circuit breaker tripped

Tags: electrical

After a high wind and rainy day, 20amp circuit breaker tripped supporting a pendent light, a GFCI receptacle and other receptacles downstream....replaced breaker but that one also tripped.  Would a bad GFCI cause this?

Comment: Does the GFCI protect any outlet or light outside?  There may be a short that has damaged the GFCI and the breaker is the last line of protection.  Check anything that was effected outside.  Disconnect any wire on the LOAD side of the GFCI and see if the breaker still trips.

Comment: Unplug everything from the receptacles and see how it goes.  If you don't like that, tell us what you need plugged in.

Comment: Leak in the roof

Answer (score 3):

Probably there's an actual fault with the circuit, so the original and replacement breakers are working fine. Replacing the breaker is far from the first step in solving "why a breaker tripped" as "breakers going bad" is rare, particularly for ones that are not AFCI or GFCI as well.

Not likely a bad GFCI - those rarely affect the breaker feeding them, they usually just fail to reset and feed  the things plugged into them or downstream of them.

But you can disconnect it.

If the problem goes away then, it's probably a Hot-Neutral short downstream of the GFCI, rather than a bad GFCI. You can check that by disconnecting only the Load wires.

If not, it's a short (Hot-Neutral or Hot-Ground) elsewhere in the circuit.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the breaker tripped means that it is *fully functional and doing its job*, not that it's faulty and needs to be replaced!

> high wind and rain

You don't tell us where any of the devices on this circuit are, but my guess is that the high wind drove the rain somewhere that shouldn't be wet, and that the water caused a short circuit. The breaker tripped, doing its job.

The fact that a second breaker tripped means that there's another fault somewhere in the system. Maybe the rain got into a receptacle and it shorted, melting wiring or the device itself, and that the short is still there, thus the new breaker tripped (again, doing exactly what it's supposed to do).

Leaving the breaker off, open up every device on this circuit, **take a picture of the wiring so you know how to put it back** and look for any damaged wires, devices or anything else that looks even remotely unexpected. If the issue isn't blindingly obvious (and it may not be) post the pics in your original question and someone else may spot the issue. While you're there, it wouldn't hurt to ensure all wires are fully seated on their terminals and that all the screws are securely fastened to the correct torque specs. A loose wire (that happened to fail during the storm, thus throwing a red herring) will also cause a short circuit.